# What is the correct use of RedirectPermanent?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, seo

I am working on an eCommerce site that passes product ids in the query string.  I just had to fix an issue where the product page didn't check the status of the product (live or archived) so if the user had a direct link e.g. a search result, the product would still display even if it had a status of "Archived".

My simple fix was to  `Response.Redirect("~/Products/Default.aspx");` if the status was not "Live".

Should I use `RedirectPermanent` in this situation even if it is possible the product may come back online?

Comment: Note: this seems more of a potential business requirement and SEO question and less of a C#/ASP.NET question. This amounts to a 301 vs. 302 redirect, and what implication that might have with Google if/when a product comes back online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that as a general rule, I only do 301 redirects whenever an actual resource/page has moved, for example when reorganizing content on a web site.

It's almost impossible to correct a 301 made by error - browsers tend to remember 301 redirects, therefore an url which is permanently redirected cannot be used again.

In your particular case, maybe a product was archived by mistake? All the visitors who visited the product's page and got 301 redirected won't be able to see the product's page, even if the product gets *un-archived*.

As to search engines, you may display a different content for archived products, and you may want to appear it differently in your `sitemap.xml` (different priority, or not at all), or you may exclude it from being indexed (`robots.txt` or by using a [robots meta](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93710)).

Answer (score 3):

IMO neither. You should display a page with the name of the product, and a message that it's no longer available. Redirect-on-error is very annoying behavior and should be avoided.

You might also want to mark the document so it doesn't get indexed by search machines. Something like:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX">
```

Comment: Totally agree, I will definitely add that functionality but I would still like to make the search engine aware of this somehow.

Comment: I have followed this exact approach today, products on Google that are no longer available. We are now showing a "sorry.." msg with the image. The benefit of this is that the breadcrumb is available along with the category the product belongs to.